# C#: Problem trying to resolve a class when two namespaces are similar

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm running into an issue where I can't make a reference to a class in a different namespace. I have 2 classes:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Class1 { ... }
}

namespace My.App.Foo
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            var x = new Foo.Class1; // compile error!
        }
    }
}
```

The compile error is:

> The type or namespace name 'Class1'
>   does not exist in the namespace
>   'My.App.Foo'

In this situation, I can't seem to get Visual Studio to recognize that "Foo.Class1" refers to the first class. If I mouse-over "Foo", it shows that its trying to resolve that to "My.App.Foo.Class1"

If I put the line:

```
using Foo;
```

at the top of the .cs file that contains Class2, then it also resolves that to "My.App.Foo".

Is there some trick to referencing the right "Foo" namespace without just renaming the namespaces so they don't conflict? Both of these namespaces are in the same assembly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `global::` to globally qualify a namespace:  `global::Foo.Class1` should work,.

You could also alias `global::Foo` to make things easier. At the top of your source file, below your using statements, add:

```
using AliasClass1=global::Foo.Class1;
```

Now you can use:

```
AliasClass1 c = new AliasClass1();
// and so on.
```

Of course, you can use a better name than `AliasClass`  :-)

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - yes I tidied that up just now.

Comment: heh, 8 years of C# development experience, and somehow i've never seen "using global::...". That works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Shame I had the right answer first, but you got all the points ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = new global::Foo.Class1();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to LBushkin's answer, you might be interested in these articles by Eric Lippert :

[Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one)
[Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part Two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two)
[Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part Three](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three)
[Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part Four](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four)

They are not directly related to your problem, but they give an interesting insight on naming strategies