# namespaces as result of the entity framework generated code

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, namespaces

I have two Reason classes:
1. One that generated by the edmx file and inherited by the object context.
2. One that I created as POCO object.

While I write my queries I need to write the full namespace of the Reason POCO class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyProj.Domain.Business.EntitiesRepository.System.Calls;

namespace MyProj.Data.EF4.EntitiesRepository.System.Calls
{
    public class ReasonRepository:
        EFRepository<MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.System.Calls.Reason>, IReasonRepository
    {
        public IList<MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.System.Calls.Reason> GetReasonsList()
        {
            return GetQuery().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

If I am not writing the full namespace the compiler consider Reason as the generated object and not as the POCO object I need.
Is there any way of preventing write the full namespace?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use using aliases .. see the example 1 in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx.

How you do it -
in your using directive do something like - 
using POCOObjects = MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.System.Calls

after that you just need to type POCOObjects.Reason

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Reason class is in the MyProj.Data.EF4.EntitiesRepository.System.Calls namespace, I think you can just add `using MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.System.Calls`

Otherwise you might want to check out this Q&A [C#: Problem trying to resolve a class when two namespaces are similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914742/c-problem-trying-to-resolve-a-class-when-two-namespaces-are-similar).  The workaround being that you use the `global::` namespace alias.  More on that here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx